# How to get Memory layer dispalyed in Vector Panel List using Pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, nearest-neighbor

I have two point layer in my Project `Centroid.shp` and `Nodes.shp`.I have used Distance Matrix to find nearest Nodes point from Centroid Point. I have saved the output in `FinalDistance.csv`. The `FinalDistance.csv` contain centroid point number, node point number and distance. No other X and Y coordinates of any of the point layer is stored in csv file. but later I realized I need to do some Sql processing in this final distance, so I tried to save as memory layer. But I couldn't get this memory layer in my Layers Panel. However when I execute manually I always get "FinalDistance" named memory layer in panel.
Or is there any way of importing csv file without having x and y cordiantes info in it.

```
   processing.run("qgis:distancematrix",{ 'INPUT' : 'C:/Final Demand Allocation/centroid.shp', 'INPUT_FIELD' : 'HMINNODE', 'TARGET' : 'C:/Final Demand Allocation/Test/Proposed_Nodes.shp', 'TARGET_FIELD' : 'id', 'MATRIX_TYPE' : 0, 'NEAREST_POINTS' : 1, 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:' })
```

Answer (score 1):

I can add a csv File in my layer panel without any Geometry Coordinates (Only Attribute Table ).

```
  uri = "file:///C:/Final Demand Allocation/finalDistance.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326"
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'finalDistance','delimitedtext')
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```